# Adding authHeader to Perl SOAP::Lite request

Tags: perl, soap

I am having some trouble creating a request to this WSDL that works; it requires authHeaders and I am not having much luck adding them. This is what I am trying:

```
# make proxy for the service
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->service($wsdl);

# add fault hanlder
$soap->on_fault(

    sub { # SOAP fault handler
        my $soap = shift;
        my $res = shift;

        # Map faults to exceptions
        if(ref($res) eq '') {
            die($res);
        }
        else {
            die($res->faultstring);
        }

        return new SOAP::SOM;
    }

);

# authentication request headers
my @headers = (
    SOAP::Header->name('user')->value('myemail@whatever.com')->uri($apins),
    SOAP::Header->name('password')->value('mypassword')->uri($apins),
    SOAP::Header->name('appName')->value('TestApp')->uri($apins),
    SOAP::Header->name('appVersion')->value('0.02')->uri($apins)
);

# request method
print $soap->getCompanyInfo('NB', @headers);
```

The response I get when doing this is:

> String value expected instead of SOAP::Header reference

The method I am requesting has two string parameters, both optional. And suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get help form the SOAP::Lite mailing list. If I want to pass my own headers, I have to use the call method instead of the actually method name.

```
# create header for requests 
my $authHeader = SOAP::Header->name("xsd:authHeader" => 
\SOAP::Header->value(
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:user')->value($s7user)->type(''),
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:password')->value($s7pass)->type(''),
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:appName')->value('TestApp')->type(''),
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:appVersion')->value('0.03')->type('')
));

# create data to pass as method paramaters
my $params = SOAP::Data->name('ns:email')->value($s7user)->type('');

# request method
$soap->call('checkLogin', $params, $authHeader);
```

In order to use the call method, you will need to define a proxy (endpoint) on your soap object. Hope this is helpful for someone else down the road.

Comment: you said "In order to use the call method, you will need to define a proxy (endpoint) on your soap object."
How can I define a proxy on my soap object ? kindly provide code

Comment: Raheel, it is in the soap constructor - example `my $soap = SOAP::Lite->proxy($url);`