# Perl SOAP::LITE -- can't authenticate?

Tags: perl, soap, authorization

I'm trying -- and failing -- to write a simple test app using SOAP::LITE to access an HP Service Manager site. (I've also tried SOAP::WSDL, but further reading made me believe that it really isn't required for what I want to do.)

I'm new to SOAP, new to these packages, and new to what I'm trying to do, so I don't know how many things I'm doing wrong, but I think I've distilled it down to a few lines of code that seem to me should work. I think the essential problem is in authentication, but I've also given some thought that it may be the way I'm trying to call the service manager routine via SOAP.

Here's the first method I found:

```
#!/usr/local/perl5/bin/perl
use SOAP::Lite+trace => 'all';

$USER = "working_user_name";
$PASS = "working_password";

sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
        print "###\n";
        print "###\n";
        print "### Authenticating...\n";
        print "###\n";
        print "###\n";
        return $USER => $PASS;
}


my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new(proxy => 'http://<hp_service_manager>:13080/SM/7/ws');
$soap->default_ns('http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7');
my $som = $soap->call('RetrieveList');
die $som->faultstring if ($som->fault);
print $som->result, "\n";
```

And the LWP method I tried:

```
#!/usr/local/perl5/bin/perl
use SOAP::Lite+trace => 'all';
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Debug;
LWP::Debug::level('+');

$USER = "working_user_name";
$PASS = "working_password";

my @ua_args = (keep_alive => 1);
my @credentials = ($SERVICE_NS, "", $USER, $PASS);
my $schema_ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(@ua_args);
$schema_ua->credentials(@credentials);

my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new(proxy => 'http://<hp_service_manager>:13080/SM/7/ws', @ua_args, credentials => \@credentials);
$soap->default_ns('http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7');
my $som = $soap->call('RetrieveList');
die $som->faultstring if ($som->fault);
print $som->result, "\n";
```

The issue is that no matter what I do I get a "not authorized" return. It's an HP Service Manager installation. I'll provide the WSDL entry for what I'm trying to do. I doubt it's useful.

```
<soap:operation soapAction="RetrieveList" style="document"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
```

While there is a lot more where this came from, this is the pertinent output, I believe:

```
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP::Request=HASH(0x845c630)
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: POST http://<service_manager>:13080/SM/7/ws HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml
Accept: multipart/*
Content-Length: 488
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "#default_ns"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><default_ns><c-gensym3 xsi:type="xsd:string">http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7</c-gensym3></default_ns></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP::Response=HASH(0x8597238)
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 15 Feb 2013 19:42:06 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CASM"
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Fri, 15 Feb 2013 19:42:07 GMT
Client-Peer: nnn.nn.nn.nn:13080
Client-Response-Num: 1

<HTML><BODY>Not Authorized</BODY></HTML>
```

Can anyone help?  I've tried pretty much every example I've been able to find, and then tried variations of those examples, and I've never managed to get any futher.  In every case I get a "Not Authorized" return.

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: Could you successfully authenticate manually using SoapUI ? I use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) whenever I am in doubt while dealing with SOAP/WSDL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be mislead: SOAP::Lite's debugging output doesn't show the Authorization header (for some reason?).

The "overriding get_basic_credentials"-method globally sets the username/password, regardless of domain and realm. Which is actually a bad thing...

This (tested) piece of code should fix your issue:

```
#!/usr/local/perl5/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use SOAP::Lite+trace => 'all';

my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new('proxy' => [
                        'http://<yourdomain>:<yourport>/<yourpath>',
                        'credentials' => [
                                "<yourdomain>:<yourport>",
                                "<yourrealm>",
                                "<yourusername>",
                                "<yourpassword>"
                        ]
                ]);
my $som = $soap->RetrieveList();
die $som->faultstring if ($som->fault);
print $som->result, "\n";
```

Where "`<yourrealm>`" should be set to "CASM", "`<yourpath>`" should be set to "/SM/7/ws",  "`<yourport>`" should be set to "13080".

*Old reply: Try doing it like this instead (note the extra asterisk):*

```
*SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials = sub { 
 return ($USER, $PASS);
}
```

Comment: I was wrong.  This method is the one that works.  However, it didn't work initially because my ID in HP Service Manager wasn't allowed to use web services.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you find this guide? http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/04/24/soap.html#security%20%28ssl,%20basic/digest%20authentication,%20cookiebased%20authentication,%20ticketbased%20authentication,%20access%20control%29

Or this answer? [Adding authHeader to Perl SOAP::Lite request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683073/adding-authheader-to-perl-soaplite-request)

```
# create header for requests 
my $authHeader = SOAP::Header->name("xsd:authHeader" => 
\SOAP::Header->value(
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:user')->value($s7user)->type(''),
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:password')->value($s7pass)->type(''),
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:appName')->value('TestApp')->type(''),
    SOAP::Header->name('xsd:appVersion')->value('0.03')->type('')
));

# create data to pass as method paramaters
my $params = SOAP::Data->name('ns:email')->value($s7user)->type('');

# request method
$soap->call('checkLogin', $params, $authHeader);
```

Comment: No luck here, either.  As for the guide, yes I had found it, and had been trying to use various methods within it.  Everything I can find out about HP Service Manager is that I need to use basic authentication.  I've tried the three methods in that guide, and none of them work.  I've also tried some of the others, still with no joy.

Comment: What is your Perl and Soap module version? Are they up to date?
Do you have other tool that is able to connect to this service? If yes, you could able  to 'sniff' the communication between the two and see what is the difference with your solution. Don't give up, it will work!

Comment: Did yoi find this? http://www.ifost.org.au/Training/ServiceManager/webperl-coursenotes.pdf